# (moment.js) format dates retrieved from mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

is there a way to format date objects stored in a mongoDB AFTER i retrieve them?

i tried **(updated)**

```
tests.find({}, {roomId: 1, teacher: 1, created: 1}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {console.log(err);}
            result = result.map(function (doc) {
                console.dir(typeof doc.created);
                console.dir(doc.created);
                doc.created = doc.created.format("MM.DD.YYYY");
                return doc;
            });

            res.render('showTests', {tests: result});
        });
```

but `cannot read property 'format' of undefined` 
(which is odd, because in jade

```
each test in tests
    p.col-md-3 #{test.roomId}
    p.col-md-3 #{test.teacher}
    p.col-md-3 #{test.created}
```

prints the date "correctly" (as a mile-long string).)

i also tried to add the format directly in jade, but that didn't work either.

do i have to store it already formatted? that can't be the only solution?

**console output (updated)**

```
'object'
Tue Feb 02 2016 20:58:36 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
f:\Dropbox\Projects\calc\routes\test.js:47
                doc.created = doc.created.format("MM.DD.YYYY");
                                          ^

TypeError: doc.created.format is not a function
```

if i comment out the .format() line, it works and shows the date in the template

**here's how i generate the date (update):**

```
var testResults = {

    addRoom: function(Id, teacher) {  // room pseudoconstructor

        this[Id] = {

            Id: Id,
            teacher: teacher,
            created: moment(),
            // ...

        }
}


    // ...
    var created = testResults[room].created;
    var students = testResults[room].students;
    var problems = testResults[room].testProblems;

 // save to DB
            var test = new tests({
                roomId      : room,
                created     : created,
                teacher     : name,
                students    : students,
                problems    : problems
            });

            test.save(function(err, result) {
                if (err) {console.log(err);}
                else {
                    console.log('test saved to DB');
                    socket.emit('testSaved');
                }
            });
```

## Answer:

https://coderwall.com/p/egh53a/making-use-of-utility-libraries-in-server-side-jade-templates

Comment: Have you tried `result.created = moment(result.created).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');` ?

Comment: `.find` will return an array of documents. You probably want `.findOne`, or you need to iterate over the results. Or you could use `moment` in the template

Comment: @ExplosionPills good point... didn't think about that. i guess a combination of both of your comments will do the trick. whoever goes first with an answer will get the tick :D

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to format a collection of documents. 
You have to loop on your results and then for every document to format its date before passing it to the template.

e.g.

```
var moment = require('moment');
result = result.map(function (doc) {
    doc.created = moment(doc.created).format("DD.MM. h:mm");
    return doc;
});
```

Comment: it didn't work. gonna have to leave this one open for now. please see my updated question

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the moment part on the date. Check the answer again. I updated it. You have to pass your date to moment and the format it.

Comment: ahhhh, now i get it. i thought it was stored as moment-object from the start.
now the error is gone, but `.format("DD.MM.YYYY");` prints `Tue Feb 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)` on the page.
`console.log` of `created` says it's `Tue Feb 02 2016 20:58:36 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)`
so the date is now wrong and no formatting applied...

Comment: If it is not a Date object then do the following 
`moment(new Date(doc.created)).format("DD.MM. h:mm");`